# How to test openfire with spark?

Tags: instant-messaging, jabber, xmpp

I have installed openfire and running on 127.0.0.1:9090. i have created a user through admin console (username=hr, password = xxx) . now i'm trying to login through spark desktop client. I'm getting invalid username or password. i double checked that the user exist in DB. What could be the possible reason for this ?